# Complex wizard pattern

Tags: c#, winforms, wizard

I'm trying to design a sceleton for my multi-wizard software and cannot find a good solution for this. All my attemts are too complex and ugly. I use NET CF and WinForms.

I have number of views: ViewA, ViewB, ViewC, ViewD etc, each view has buttons "back", "next" and "cancel"

These views are used by wizards like below, each wizard has entry pont and end point, also it can be cancelled.

```
WzrdA: -> ViewA <-> ViewB <-> ViewC ->
WzrdB: -> ViewB <-> ViewD -> 
WzrdC: -> ViewC <-> ViewD ->
```

And finally wizards are combined to workflows:

```
WfA: ViewMain (start WfA) -> WzrdA -> WzrdB -> WzrdC -> back to ViewMain
WfB: ViewMain (start WfB) -> WzrdA -> WzrdC -> back to ViewMain
```

So, I have single main view with two buttons "Start WfA" and "Start WfB" in this case workflow "WfB", for example, has to show follow views:

```
 -> ViewA <-> ViewB <-> ViewC ->   ViewC <-> ViewD ->
```

that sequence describes back/next buttons, if cancel buttun was pressed it has to be moved to the main view immediately.

Does anybody know a clear and nice solution for this problem?

Comment: What collection are you using to contain the wizard "pages"?

Comment: I'm confused on the relation between views, wizards and workflows. Does this mean if I run WfA, I see (expanding out wizards -> views): ViewA, ViewB, ViewC, ViewB, ViewD, ViewC, ViewD ? Are they the same form/template, just used to display different data, or am I actually seeing the same thing over and over?

Answer (score 2):

The following concept (from your post) violates DRY, SRP and OOP generally:

> each view has buttons "back", "next" and "cancel"

For a wizard framework you would normally have a single, parent view that hosts those buttons. There should be a controller that manages the collection of pages (LinkedList<> seems like a natural fit) and loads the pages into the parent according to your flow logic.

The general architecture I'm describing here fits MVC. [Check it out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

More: Your wizard container can be a Form (with a resizeable panel to host pages) but your pages need to be custom controls so that you can host them within the parent.